# What's the best way to add an on/off switch for a battery to a circuit?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, switches

The circuit I have contains a TP4056, a lithium-polymer battery, an accelerometer, and an ESP32. Wondering where and how to apply an on/off switch. Or if there is any specific switch name to add (one that can be wired into a circuit).

Comment: You need to link the data sheet for the product and also add photographs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "what to apply an on/off switch" means, but using it to interrupt the + wire between the TP4056 module and the ESP32 would be the usual place to put it.

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend a specific on/off switch or any is okay

Comment: Specific product recommendations are off topic here but any switch with a DC current rating that matches or exceeds the amount of current you expect the system to use and a DC voltage rating that matches or exceeds the maximum voltage you expect the system to experience will work.

Comment: Thanks. I meant the kind of switch like a rocker or toggle switch but I think I might go for whichever I can find. Additionally, I have a battery of 3.7V and 1100mAH therefore I'm finding it difficult to find a switch that matches as most say 12V or 150V. Or is there different terminology for the switches.

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce a toggle switch in one of the battery leads.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

If you decide to have a on off switch you have to put a flyback diode to protect the battery from any reverse current due to parasitic inductances.

Comment: If so, how many devices with an on off switch you have seen with a flyback diode? Where would the flyback diode be located, at the battery, switch or the device? Please draw a diagram that matches your suggestion.